# i2p. Как открыть порт 7657?

Tags: сеть, роутинг

Роутер находится по адресу http://127.0.0.1:7657.
При установке i2p столкнулся с проблемой. Роутер выдает ошибку: порт закрыт брандмауэром. Просканировал с помощью стороннего сериса, выдал, что порт 7657 закрыт. Читал в интернетах, что это из-за "серого" IP. Настроил выход через прокси 127.0.0.1:4444, исключая локалхост, как нужно. Как поднять сеть i2p? В интернетах конкретно этой проблемы я не нашел, хотя, очевидно, она есть.

Comment: я думаю, Вы понимаете, что такое 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Понимаю, и что?

Comment: если сервер слушает только на 127.0.0.1, то "просканировал стороннем сервисом" выглядит немного странно. Да, он по любому будет закрыт, так как его никто и не открывал.

Comment: Сеть на 4444, роутер на 7657.

Comment: Он закрыт, но другие узлы обращаются к нему извне через этот порт внутри сети.

Comment: Так что же такое 127.0.0.1? Маршрут то на lo

Comment: Тогда почему порт закрыт?

Comment: Мне нужно только решить проблему с сетью, чтобы можно было подключаться к другим узлам в сети.